# Detect whether a font is installed on client browser?

Tags: sharepoint, browser, fonts

I have a requirement where I need to check in my SharePoint page whether a custom font is installed on the browser running it or not. Accordingly I need to update a CSS class which makes the use of that font.

So is there any way through which I can detect that whether a font is available on client browser (IE and Firefox)?

Comment: I don't think this really has anything to do with SharePoint (and certainly not 2007). Yes its running on SP but is there anything about the question that is specific to SP? If not then is it better on StackOverflow?

Answer (score 0):

[This javascript method](http://lucassmith.name/2009/05/test-if-a-font-is-installed-via-javascript.html) seems to work -- check out the [test page](http://lucassmith.name/pub/font_installed.html).

Comment: This dosent seem to work when u have custom fonts. I tried testing for Helvetica font which is not installed on my system but then also it retutrns yes.